# What options one has for creating an MPI cluster on top of Windows Azure?

Tags: linux, windows, azure

So my problem is simple - is there a way to create an MPI cluster of `N` nodes on top of Windows Azure in a fashon as light as possible? Linux or Windows Server based. Main thing is to be able to create and configure all nodes (connect one to another and install basic applications) in as less human action as possible. Is it possible and how to do it?

I know there are management APIs provided with Azure that can create and start preconfigured VMs yet I see no way to on how to automate nodes interconnection process without writing an application by my self. Are there any simpler ways of starting MPI cluster in Windows Azure?

Comment: Editing an old question into something completely new is not acceptable,  especially not to game our system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read this article : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn592104.aspx - by using HPC Pack?

and without HPC http://blog.rescale.com/azure-ms-mpi-in-a-box/

If this solutions is not good for you - you can use another solution: 
I don't know how actually MPI work now, but that, there is at least two roles: master node and worker nodes.

register every node on your own DynDNS server (as i remember powerdns have pretty API for manage zones)
let master node read DNS records for worker. Assign your own logic at this point.

For example - two nodes register on dyndns as worker1 and worker2.
By cron or any other method you read DNS zone (may be from mysql) by master node. Ok, you have 22 nodes in cluster. Work with them.

Some time later you add 3rd node. It register as worker3.
Master by cron read, that it have 3 nodes. And work this additional node.